# Dropdown Menu with Ember.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, handlebars.js

I can't get my ember and bootstrap drop down menu to work. It doesn't even show.
Hbs is below. I'm using yeoman as the build.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul>
  {{#link-to 'index' class="navbar-brand"}}<i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;Home{{/link-to}}
  {{#link-to 'about' class="navbar-brand"}}About Me{{/link-to}}
  {{#link-to 'portfolio' class="navbar-brand"}}Portfolio{{/link-to}}
  {{#link-to 'hereIam' class="navbar-brand"}}Here I am{{/link-to}}
  {{#link-to 'contact' class="navbar-brand"}}<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp;Contact Me{{/link-to}}
      {{#dropdown-list selected=selected item="default"}}
        {{partial "dropdown-menu"}}
      {{/dropdown-list}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the dropdowns.js:

```
Earthstewarddesigns.DropdownListComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: 'btn-group',
  isDropdownVisible: false,

  btnClassName: function(){
    return 'btn-'+this.get('item');
  }.property('item'),

  actions: {
    toggle: function(item){
      this.toggleProperty('isDropdownVisible');
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the View:

```
Earthstewarddesigns.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  classNames: 'dropdowns',

  click: function(e){
    if (jQuery(e.target).is('.dropdowns')){
      jQuery('ul.dropdown-menu').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

And Last the templates:

_dropdown-menu.hbs:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
      {{#link-to 'watering'}}Action{{/link-to}}
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
```

component/dropdown-list.hbs:

```
<button type="button" {{bind-attr class=":btn :dropdown-toggle btnClassName"}} {{action "toggle"}}> {{item}} <span class="caret"></span> </button>

{{#if isDropdownVisible}}
    {{yield}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Can you make a http://emberjs.jsbin.com of your issue? I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do.

The built in dropdown js from bootstrap seems to work fine. Here's [an example with multiple dropdowns](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mofomo/2/edit?html,js,output).